# Dont understand why the color binding varies between Fill and GradientStop

Tags: wpf, controltemplates

I'm trying to get to grips with ControlTemplates in WPF. I noticed that when you try to reference a templated parent's background color - the binding statement seems to be different for elipse Fill and elipse GradientStop. Can any one explain why this is.

This works...

```
<Ellipse RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"  Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}">
```

This works...

```
<GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background.Color}"/>
```

This doesnt work - why is this?

```
<GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{TemplatedParent Background}"/>
```

This produces an error...

```
<GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{TemplatedParent Background.Color}"/>
```

This doesnt work...

```
<Ellipse RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"  Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background.Color}">
```

The instance looks like this...

```
        <Button Template="{StaticResource buttonTemplate1}"
            Height="100" Width="100" FontSize="40" 
            Background="Violet" Foreground="Aquamarine"
            Padding="0" Margin="6">Button 5</Button>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the types of the Fill and the Color properties? The one is a Brush, the other a Color, which is *not the same type*.

Comment: `TemplatedParent` is not a markup extension. secondly `Fill` is kind of `Brush` instead of `Color`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you need to distinguish between `Brush` and `Color` type properties.

- `Brush`-typed properties are used by controls, and include `Fill`, `Stroke`, and `Background`.
- The most common use of `Color` is as a component of a `Brush`, either the color of a `SolidColorBrush`, or the color of a `GradientStop` of a `LinearGradientBrush`.

There are also some binding syntax errors in the examples you posted.

---

> This doesnt work - why is this?

```
<GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{TemplatedParent Background}"/>
```

That's not a valid binding syntax.  But assuming you meant `TemplateBinding Background`, then it's still not valid, because the target `Color` is a different type than the source `Background` (`Brush`).

---

> This produces an error...

```
<GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{TemplatedParent Background.Color}"/>
```

Same issue as above, you mean `TemplateBinding` instead of `TemplatedParent`.  And, I believe that in any case `TemplateBinding` won't work for a nested property.  You would need to write:

```
<GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{TemplateBinding 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background.Color}" />
```

---

> This doesnt work...

```
<Ellipse RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"  Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background.Color}">
```

The syntax is correct here, but the types don't match -- the target is `Brush`, and the source is `System.Color`.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the detailed explanation.